# Tabpage autosize? (Dock = fill ?)

Tags: c#, user-interface

I have a resizable form which contains some tabpages.
Now I want those tabpages to be autosized to the size of the parent form.

TabPage seems to have no function like 'Dock'

Comment: C# does not have any UI. You should tag `WPF`, `Winforms`, etc. to identify what kind of UI Framework you are working with.

Comment: You dock the TabControl, not the TabPage.

Comment: Thx a lot guys! that fixed it!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Dock the `TabControl` that contains the `TabPages` instead. Click on the empty space besides the tabs in the form designer to select the `TabControl`.

The Parent<-Child correlations are basically like

`Form<-TabControl<-TabPage<-Controls on the TabPage`

Since the `TabControl` is therefore the actual container for all `TabPages`, you should use it's docking property for positioning on the form.

Comment: Thx a lot guys! that fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

What about the "Anchor" Property?

Example to set it programmatically
`item.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right);`